# Enviar um Bad Request por REST

Tags: c#

Um método meu pega o valor de campo. Se este campo for null ou zero, deve ser enviado um Bad Request para o usuário indicando o ID do campo e informar que ele não pode ser null. Isso é um serviço REST. Estou montando o código(um foreach) e dentro desse foreach ele vai cuspindo esses BAD REQUEST caso haja. Como eu faço para gerar um bad request dentro de um rest?

Comment: O que eu entendo como "bad request" é código num cabeçalho HTTP da resposta. E nesse caso a resposta nem conteria muito mais informações. Mas isso você não poderia cuspir várias vezes dentro de um foreach, somente uma, e em seguida enviar a resposta ao cliente.

Comment: Eu geralmente retorno `200` e um `JSON` ou `XML` com as informações adicionais.

Comment: @RobertodeCampos sinto dizer mas retornar falando que está "tudo bem" é complicado. Se você for o responsável pelo servidor e pelo cliente, então você consegue gerir isso muito bem. Caso contrário, muitas aplicações/programadores assumem que código 200 é que deu sucesso. Use erro na faixa 4XX para erros de requisição (cliente não soube falar o que queria/cliente ocasionou o erro) e 5XX para erros no lado do servidor.

Comment: @pnet, um BAD REQUEST em si é só um código HTTP, se não me engano é o 400. Em alguns sistemas REST simplesmente informar isso é o suficiente. Por exemplo, como eu só preciso falar com aplicações cliente que são máquinas (sem interagir com pessoas), eu só retorno o código de erro. Mas não é seu caso, para você é interessante retornar também a mensagem/as mensagens de erro. Eu arriscaria uma resposta em Java, onde posso retornar uma string arbitrária e um código HTTP também arbitrário. Mas não conheço C# a esse ponto

Comment: A dúvida está em como fazer isso. Existe um serviço que valida se o cara preencheu ou não um campo. Esse campo é obrigatório

Comment: Alguém conhece algum link que explique em como enviar uma bad request por meio de um rest? O que realmente devo fazer, ou melhor, como

Comment: Como eu faço para retornar um code 400, por exemplo? Como eu faço isso?

Comment: Você esta usando web.api? Se tiver a sua action pode retornar um BadRequest() desde que seu retorno seja IActionResult.

Comment: @GabrielColetta, é isso mesmo. Só me tire uma dúvida. Eu preciso nesse BadRequest informar os produtos que estão sem serial. Eu monto um objeto com esse valores e coloco no parâmetro do badRequest tipo: return BadRequest(meu_objeto); é isso mesmo?

Comment: BadRequest não aceita um objeto, apenas string. Se você utilizar o StringBuilder e montar a mensagem daria certo.

Comment: @bfavaretto O [rfc7231](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5) discorda. `the  server SHOULD send a representation containing an explanation of the error situation`. Mas sim a resposta é só uma (nao há vários bad requests). Também poderia ser um [`Multi-Status`](https://restpatterns.mindtouch.us/HTTP_Status_Codes/207_-_Multi-Status)

Answer (score 1):

O `MVC` já faz a validacao automática do Modelo por voce mesmo. Para obter os erros do seu modelo voce pode aceder á propriedade `ModelState`. Exemplo:

```
var errors = string.join(" ", ModelState.SelectMany(s => s.Value.Errors)
    .Select(e => e.ErrorMessage))
if(errors.Length > 0){
    return BadRequest(errors);
}
```

Para apresentar mensagens amigáveis para o utilizador voce deve configurar a propriedade `ErrorMessage` nos seus atributos de validacao, no seu modelo. Exemplo:

```
public class Modelo {
    [StringLength(1, ErrorMessage = "Introduza um nome válido")]
    public string Name{get;set;}
}
```

Caso isso nao seja suficiente para si. Pode sempre validar o modelo programáticamente para saber quais sao os erros. Exemplo:

```
var context = new ValidationContext(model, null, null);
var results = new List<ValidationResult>();

bool valid = Validator.TryValidateObject(model, context, results, true);
if (valid)
{
    return Task.CompletedTask;
}

var errors = string.Join(" ", results.Select(e => e.ErrorMessage));
throw new InvalidOperationException($"Can not insert because data is not valid. {errors}");
```